# Shell script won't run on Android but will on Ubuntu

Tags: android, unix, shell

This script was written to make changes to the build.prop file on rooted devices.  It will run on ubuntu but throws the following error when it is ran on a device. 6: Syntax error: expecting "in"

```
LINE_BREAK=""
while read line
do
    case $line in
        ro.ril.reject.cs.ss.enabled?=*)
            line="ro.ril.reject.cs.ss.enabled=1";;
        ro.ril.reject.mo.ussd.enabled?=*)
            line="ro.ril.reject.mo.ussd.enabled=1";;
        ro.phone.function?=*)
            line="ro.phone.function=0";;
        ro.bt.profiles?=*)
            line="ro.bt.profiles=4270339";;
        service.brcm.bt.ag_supported?=*)
            line="service.brcm.bt.ag_supported=0";;
    esac
    NEW_FILE="$NEW_FILE$LINE_BREAK$line"
    LINE_BREAK="\n"
done </system/build.prop
echo $NEW_FILE>/system/build.prop
```

Is there a nuance to writing scripts in android that I am missing? Thanks in advance!

Comment: did you try SL4A for writing the scripts? It makes such tasks much easy.

Comment: No, I will try that, I'll let you know what happens

Comment: When I wrote the script in SL4A it worked. If you submit it as an answer I will accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try writing a script using SL4A which is the scripting layer for android. 
Reference
http://android.amolgupta.in/2011/04/scripting-on-android.html

Answer (score 0):

I do not have an Android but I would try putting quotes around $line:

```
case "$line" in
```

Just a hunch. Sorry about that. Maybe you tried already.